# Merge two dataframes with partial column name match

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge/concatenate two dataframes `tcia` and `clin`. In contrast to the `tcia` dataframe, the `clin` dataframe has a substring at the end of the column names (i.e., the 3rd "-" followed by subsequent letters). The dataframes should be combined irrespective of the substring but the final dataframe should have this substring.

My code does the job but I'm hoping for a more robust/concise way to do it.

Code:

```
clin_df = clin.copy()
clin_df.columns = clin_df.columns.str.rsplit('-', n=1).str.get(0)
df = pd.concat([clin_df, tcia], axis=0)
df.columns = clin.columns
```

Input:
`clin`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '53',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '207.0',
  'ethnicity': 'not hispanic or latino'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '71',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '2298.0',
  'ethnicity': 'not hispanic or latino'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '67',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': nan,
  'ethnicity': 'not hispanic or latino'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '60',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '1731.0',
  'ethnicity': 'not hispanic or latino'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J7-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '63',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': nan,
  'ethnicity': 'not hispanic or latino'}})
```

`tcia`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-2K-A9WE': {'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg': 8.0,
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos': 7.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg': 7.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos': 6.0,
  'patient_uuid': '73292c19-d6a8-4bc4-97bc-ccce54f264f8'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1': {'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg': 9.0,
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos': 8.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg': 9.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos': 7.0,
  'patient_uuid': '851a1157-e460-4794-8534-2eb6f0ae7468'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3': {'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg': 9.0,
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos': 7.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg': 8.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos': 6.0,
  'patient_uuid': '5195c9ac-b649-49f8-8750-f9a4787e8e52'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J6': {'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg': 9.0,
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos': 7.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg': 8.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos': 7.0,
  'patient_uuid': '4a540448-f106-4b0e-9038-9f7ccefc785b'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J7': {'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg': 7.0,
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos': 5.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg': 6.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos': 5.0,
  'patient_uuid': 'd66c9261-6c0c-44b0-92fa-a43757f34cb2'}})
```

Desired output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-2K-A9WE': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '53',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '207.0',
  'ethnicity': 'not hispanic or latino',
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg': 8.0,
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos': 7.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg': 7.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos': 6.0,
  'patient_uuid': '73292c19-d6a8-4bc4-97bc-ccce54f264f8'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '71',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '2298.0',
  'ethnicity': 'not hispanic or latino',
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg': 9.0,
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos': 8.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg': 9.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos': 7.0,
  'patient_uuid': '851a1157-e460-4794-8534-2eb6f0ae7468'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '67',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': nan,
  'ethnicity': 'not hispanic or latino',
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg': 9.0,
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos': 7.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg': 8.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos': 6.0,
  'patient_uuid': '5195c9ac-b649-49f8-8750-f9a4787e8e52'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J6': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '60',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '1731.0',
  'ethnicity': 'not hispanic or latino',
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg': 9.0,
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos': 7.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg': 8.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos': 7.0,
  'patient_uuid': '4a540448-f106-4b0e-9038-9f7ccefc785b'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J7': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '63',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': nan,
  'ethnicity': 'not hispanic or latino',
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg': 7.0,
  'ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos': 5.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg': 6.0,
  'ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos': 5.0,
  'patient_uuid': 'd66c9261-6c0c-44b0-92fa-a43757f34cb2'}})
```

Comment: "but the final dataframe should have this substring" - I guess the desired df output shown should have those suffixes (though it's missing them).

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but are you sure this data has been processed right? You've got `age` as a row of strings, but conventionally it should be a column of numbers. With the data transposed, then you could use `.merge`, which would also make more sense IMHO. FWIW, to use these dicts verbatim, `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(orient='index', data=...)` (with `nan = np.nan`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`df.set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) method (to assign a new column index on-the-fly):

```
df = pd.concat([clin.set_axis(clin.columns.str.rpartition('-', expand=False).str[0], axis=1),
                tcia]).set_axis(clin.columns, axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
                                                           TCGA-2K-A9WE-01                       TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01                       TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01                       TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01                       TCGA-2Z-A9J7-01
admin.batch_number                                                398.45.0                              398.45.0                              398.45.0                              398.45.0                              398.45.0
age                                                                     53                                    71                                    67                                    60                                    63
days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis                                     0                                     0                                     0                                     0                                     0
days_to_last_follow_up                                               207.0                                2298.0                                   NaN                                1731.0                                   NaN
ethnicity                                           not hispanic or latino                not hispanic or latino                not hispanic or latino                not hispanic or latino                not hispanic or latino
ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg                                                  8.0                                   9.0                                   9.0                                   9.0                                   7.0
ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos                                                  7.0                                   8.0                                   7.0                                   7.0                                   5.0
ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg                                                  7.0                                   9.0                                   8.0                                   8.0                                   6.0
ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos                                                  6.0                                   7.0                                   6.0                                   7.0                                   5.0
patient_uuid                          73292c19-d6a8-4bc4-97bc-ccce54f264f8  851a1157-e460-4794-8534-2eb6f0ae7468  5195c9ac-b649-49f8-8750-f9a4787e8e52  4a540448-f106-4b0e-9038-9f7ccefc785b  d66c9261-6c0c-44b0-92fa-a43757f34cb2
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
clin.columns = [c.rsplit("-", maxsplit=1)[0] for c in clin.columns]

out = pd.concat([clin, tcia])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                                                              TCGA-2K-A9WE                          TCGA-2Z-A9J1                          TCGA-2Z-A9J3                          TCGA-2Z-A9J6                          TCGA-2Z-A9J7
admin.batch_number                                                398.45.0                              398.45.0                              398.45.0                              398.45.0                              398.45.0
age                                                                     53                                    71                                    67                                    60                                    63
days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis                                     0                                     0                                     0                                     0                                     0
days_to_last_follow_up                                               207.0                                2298.0                                   NaN                                1731.0                                   NaN
ethnicity                                           not hispanic or latino                not hispanic or latino                not hispanic or latino                not hispanic or latino                not hispanic or latino
ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_neg                                                  8.0                                   9.0                                   9.0                                   9.0                                   7.0
ips_ctla4_neg_pd1_pos                                                  7.0                                   8.0                                   7.0                                   7.0                                   5.0
ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_neg                                                  7.0                                   9.0                                   8.0                                   8.0                                   6.0
ips_ctla4_pos_pd1_pos                                                  6.0                                   7.0                                   6.0                                   7.0                                   5.0
patient_uuid                          73292c19-d6a8-4bc4-97bc-ccce54f264f8  851a1157-e460-4794-8534-2eb6f0ae7468  5195c9ac-b649-49f8-8750-f9a4787e8e52  4a540448-f106-4b0e-9038-9f7ccefc785b  d66c9261-6c0c-44b0-92fa-a43757f34cb2
```